# better way to use index array to get elements?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to get the elements of a `numpy` array using an index array like so

```
import numpy 
a = numpy.arange(6)
ind = [2,3]
```

now, `a[ind]` gives me the 3rd and 4th element, but I actually want all the *other* elements of `a`. 
Is there a one line/ elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a straightforward way I know of to get the complement of a set of integer indices. Boolean index negation is easy, which lets you do something like this:

```
In [100]: a=np.arange(6)

In [101]: ind=[2,3]

In [102]: cind=(a==a)

In [103]: cind[ind]=False

In [104]: a[cind]
Out[104]: array([0, 1, 4, 5])
```

But it isn't a one line solution.

Comment: you can use `np.ones(a.shape, 'bool')` instead of `(a==a)`

Answer (score 1):

maybe like this:

```
import numpy  
a = numpy.arange(6) 
ind = [1,3]
for x in range(6):
 if x not in ind: print a[x]
```

Answer (score 1):

This has been suggested here before, but this is a list comprehension and therefore a oneliner:

```
numpy.array([a[i] for i in range(len(a)) if i not in ind])
```

results in

```
array([0, 1, 4, 5])
```