# Return elements not referenced by array of indices in Python

Tags: python, numpy

Say I have an array in Python, e.g.:

```
my_array = np.array([10, -5, 4, ...])
my_indices = np.array([0, 3, 10, ...])
```

How can I **efficiently** get:

1. The list of **indices** of `my_array` that are not in `my_indices`
2. The list of **elements** in `my_array` not **referenced** by `my_indices` (trivial with 1, but perhaps there is a direct way)

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. It'd be more useful if you showed actual inputs and expected outputs for each question

Comment: Possible dupe?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8741445/better-way-to-use-index-array-to-get-elements/8741884#8741884 -- This question asks for a little bit more than the previous one however ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I might do it something like this:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.random.random(10)  # set up a random array to play with
>>> a
array([ 0.20291643,  0.89973074,  0.14291639,  0.53535553,  0.21801353,
        0.05582776,  0.64301145,  0.56081956,  0.85771335,  0.6032354 ])
>>>
>>> b = np.array([0,5,6,9])  # indices we *don't want*
>>> mask = np.ones(a.shape,dtype=bool)
>>> mask[b] = False          # Converted to a mask array of indices we *do want*
>>> mask
array([False,  True,  True,  True,  True, False, False,  True,  True, False], dtype=bool)
>>>
>>> np.arange(a.shape[0])[mask]  #This gets you the indices that aren't in your original
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8])
>>> a[mask]  #This gets you the elements not in your original.
array([ 0.89973074,  0.14291639,  0.53535553,  0.21801353,  0.56081956,
        0.85771335])
```

Comment: My inuition tells me that this is the most efficient of all answers (I would guess that indexing is "more vectorized" than list comprehensions). What do you think?

Comment: @user273158 -- There may be a better numpy way to do it still.  Really though, you'd need to `timeit` to know for sure what you're best option is.

Answer (score 2):

For part 1, you can just use the difference between the two sets using Python's [built in `set`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) class.

```
my_array = [1,2,3,4]
my_indices = [3,4,5]

print list(set(my_array) - set(my_indices))
```

Will output: `[1, 2]`.

---

**EDIT**

In order to return the list of indices in `my_array` that are not in `my_indices`, you could use list comprehension:

```
my_array = [1,2,3,4]
my_indices = [0,3]

print [x for x in range(len(my_array)) if x not in my_indices]
```

Which can also be expressed as:

```
temp = []
for x in range(len(my_array)):
  if x not in my_indices:
    temp.append(x)
```

This will return the indices `[1,2]`.

In you wanted to get the list of elements, then you can modify the statement to be:

```
print [my_array[x] for x in range(len(my_array)) if x not in my_indices]
```

Which will output `[2,3]`.

Comment: Thanks, but in my first question I am looking for **indices** of `my_array`, not its elements, and in my second question I am looking for elements not **referenced** by `my_indices`. Your answer, while admittedly solves another problem, does not address these questions.

Comment: Ah okay. I think I understand. I've modified my answer.

Answer (score 1):

For the first question:

```
my_indices_set = set(my_indices)
[i for i, x in enumerate(my_array) if i not in my_indices]
```

For the second question:

```
[x for x in my_array if x not in my_indices_set]
```

It's more efficient if we use sets, but then there's the cost of creating the sets in the first place

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehensions

```
array_len = len(my_array)
missing_indices = [i for i in my_indices
                   if i < 0 or i >= array_len]
elems = [my_array[i] for i in missing_indices]
```